# I can't find any product as a customer from a new customer group created in magento 2.4 CE any idea why?

Tags: catalog, magento2.4, customer-group

My site is running on magento 2.4 CE with elastic search. I've been adding products and checking various features of magento. trying to create a group of customers whom i can give discounts on products. But user from new group cant find any product on website.

Answer (score 0):

You might have selected an option on the Excluded Website(s) checkbox when creating the customer group

[image]

In the screenshot above if I create the "Sample" group and assign a customer to it they would not be able to see any products on the frontend.